# Looking for well established .Net CMS that supports direct querying of SQL Tables and/or Views

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, webforms, content-management-system

I currently use Sitefinity which does have a SQL Database but they discourage people from accessing it directly. Is there a CMS that actually supports/encourages direct access of database Tables/Views? Ideally it would support both MVC and WebForms. Needs to be .Net.

Answer (score 3):

You could try BetterCMS http://www.bettercms.com/

They have an API on the CMS: http://www.bettercms.com/documentation/api-available-methods

I haven't used the API, but have use the CMS integrated into an application for content pages and works well.

Answer (score 0):

if you know what you are doing then sure - you can access the sql tables directly.

It is not recommended in some scenarios because:

1. You probably do not know all relations between the tables and inserting/deleting records from just 1 table may not be enough, especially when you have multiple languages with split tables.
2. doing a CRUD operations directly in the sql tables will probably get unnoticed by the CMS until after the site restarts. This is due to the caching mechanism.

That is why it is recommended to use the Sitefinity API which takes care of working with the correct tables and also refreshes the cache appropriately.

Let me give you an example - let's say you wanted to delete a single image by it's fileId for instance.

using the API requires only a couple of lines of code:

```
 var imageToDelete = libraryManager.GetImages()
                                   .Where(i => i.FileId == fileId)
                                   .FirstOrDefault();

 if (imageToDelete != null)
 {
     libraryManager.DeleteImage(imageToDelete);
     libraryManager.SaveChanges();
 }
```

Now, if you try to delete the same image with SQL command you would need something like this:

```
declare @fileId nvarchar(255)
set @fileId = 'f715a35d-5724-434b-b6cc-c00bcda93d6c'

delete from sf_md_cntnt_pblshd_trnslations
where content_id in (select content_id from sf_media_content
where file_id = @fileId)

delete from sf_md_content_sf_language_data
where content_id in (select content_id from sf_media_content
where file_id = @fileId)

delete from sf_mdia_content_sf_permissions
where content_id in (select content_id from sf_media_content
where file_id = @fileId)

delete from sf_url_data
where content_id in (select content_id from  sf_media_content
where file_id = @fileId)

select * from sf_media_thumbnails
where content_id in (select content_id from  sf_media_content
where file_id = @fileId)

delete from sf_media_content
where file_id = @fileId
```

And this is only if I am not missing any table :)

So, I can understand why the support recommended using the API as opposed to using the database directly.

But, again, if you know what you are doing - go ahead.